# write zip file content from memory to a console app

Tags: c#, console, zip

am sorry but I don't know where to start
I need a way to use files from zip file in real time as they get unziped
like to write from file stream
the console app is a samsung odin flash program
and the arguments to it like
`odin --flash --recovery /recovery.img path --boot /boot.img path etc`
and unziping samsung firmware files take too much duo to large size of some of the files in it
so am looking for a way to make the argument go like
`odin --flash --recovery 'stream providing the recovery.img file as it unzip'`
I don't know if that possible but I hope there is a way to do that

I didn't try any thing because I don't know where to start

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible because `odin` expects a file name, not a stream of data.
If you wanted to print a decompressed file from a .zip to the console, you'd do something like this:

```cs
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;

static void PrintZipFile(string zipPath, int fileIndex)
{
    using var zip = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath);
    using Stream firstEntry = zip.Entries[fileIndex].Open();
    using var r = new BinaryReader(firstEntry);

    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(r.ReadBytes((int)r.BaseStream.Length)));
}
```

Comment: if I can't just stream the file directly to odin can I at least get it to read files as they get unziped the unzip process is a lot faster than odin read speed I think ?

Comment: No, that isn't possible.